# How do I select an element in array column of a data frame?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
pa=pd.DataFrame({'a':np.array([[1.,4.],[2.],[3.,4.,5.]])})
```

I want to select the column 'a' and then only a particular element (i.e. first: 1., 2., 3.)

What do I need to add to:

```
pa.loc[:,['a']]
```

?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`pa.loc[row]` selects the row with label `row`.

`pa.loc[row, col]` selects the cells which are the instersection of `row` and `col`

`pa.loc[:, col]` selects *all* rows and the column named `col`. Note that although this works it is not the idiomatic way to refer to a column of a dataframe. For that you should use `pa['a']`

Now you have lists in the cells of your column so you can use the [vectorized string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods) to access the elements of those lists like so.

```
pa['a'].str[0] #first value in lists
pa['a'].str[-1] #last value in lists
```

Comment: does `pa['a'].str[:]` work to access all elements ?

Answer (score 11):

Storing lists as values in a Pandas DataFrame tends to be a mistake because
it prevents you from taking advantage of fast NumPy or Pandas vectorized operations.

Therefore, you might be better off converting your DataFrame of lists of numbers into a wider DataFrame with native NumPy dtypes:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pa = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.array([[1.,4.],[2.],[3.,4.,5.]])})
df = pd.DataFrame(pa['a'].values.tolist())
#      0    1    2
# 0  1.0  4.0  NaN
# 1  2.0  NaN  NaN
# 2  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

Now, you could select the first column like this:

```
In [36]: df.iloc[:, 0]
Out[36]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

or the first row like this:

```
In [37]: df.iloc[0, :]
Out[37]: 
0    1.0
1    4.0
2    NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

If you wish to drop NaNs, use `.dropna()`:

```
In [38]: df.iloc[0, :].dropna()
Out[38]: 
0    1.0
1    4.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

and `.tolist()` to retrieve the values as a list:

```
In [39]: df.iloc[0, :].dropna().tolist()
Out[39]: [1.0, 4.0]
```

but if you wish to leverage NumPy/Pandas for speed, you'll want to express your calculation as vectorized operations on `df` itself without converting back to Python lists.