# Splitting a string in a Python DataFrame

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in Python with a column with names (such as Joseph Haydn, Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart, Antonio Salieri and so forth).

I want to get a new column with the last names: Haydn, Mozart, Salieri and so forth.

I know how to split a string, but I could not find a way to apply it to a series, or a Data Frame column.

Comment: `column.str.split`. Add some example code, and you will likely get an answer.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 30):

if you have:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame({"composers": [ 
    "Joseph Haydn", 
    "Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart", 
    "Antonio Salieri",
    "Eumir Deodato"]})
```

assuming you want only the first name (and not the middle name like Amadeus):

```
data.composers.str.split('\s+').str[0]
```

will give:

```
0      Joseph
1    Wolfgang
2     Antonio
3       Eumir
dtype: object
```

you can assign this to a new column in the same dataframe:

```
data['firstnames'] = data.composers.str.split('\s+').str[0]
```

Last names would be:

```
data.composers.str.split('\s+').str[-1]
```

which gives:

```
0      Haydn
1     Mozart
2    Salieri
3    Deodato
dtype: object
```

(see also [Python Pandas: selecting element in array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069235/python-pandas-selecting-element-in-array-column) for accessing elements in an 'array' column)

For all but the last names you can apply `" ".join(..)` to all but the last element (`[:-1]`) of each row:

```
data.composers.str.split('\s+').str[:-1].apply(lambda parts: " ".join(parts))
```

which gives:

```
0              Joseph
1    Wolfgang Amadeus
2             Antonio
3               Eumir
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Andre. I have almost arrived to the same solution, but yours is more elegant. In any case I was intrigued by the double use of "str" in "data.composers.str.split('\s+').str[-1]". Would never be able to deduce that by logic alone. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I arrived at this solution iteratively, e.g. by googling 'pandas dataframe strings' I found http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html where I searched for `split` (incidentally, you'll also find an example about split when you do `help(data.composers)` (after the variable data has been defined as above). The second part (accessing elements of columns whose entries are lists themselves) I found in the linked answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069235/python-pandas-selecting-element-in-array-column

Comment: I don't think you need `'\s+'`. That's the default of `split()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to solve your problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'composers':
        [ 
            'Joseph Haydn', 
            'Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart', 
            'Antonio Salieri',
            'Eumir Deodato',
        ]
    }
)

df['lastname'] = df['composers'].str.split(n = 0, expand = False).str[1]
```

You can now find the DataFrame, as shown below.

```py
composers   lastname
0   Joseph Haydn    Haydn
1   Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart Amadeus Mozart
2   Antonio Salieri Salieri
3   Eumir Deodato   Deodato
```

Comment: `str[1]` is  the wrong index. It just appears to work on this cherry-picked input, but breaks on others. If your df has Mozart first, it gives "Amadeus" for that column rather than "Mozart". Better: `df['composers'].str.split().str[-1]` but then it's basically the same as the existing answer, so I don't think this answer adds value even if fixed.