# Python Pandas: selecting 1st element in array in all cells

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What I am trying to do is select the 1st element of each cell regardless of the number of columns or rows (they may change based on user defined criteria)  and make a new pandas dataframe from the data. My actual data structure is similar to what I have listed below.

```
       0       1       2
0   [1, 2]  [2, 3]  [3, 6]
1   [4, 2]  [1, 4]  [4, 6]
2   [1, 2]  [2, 3]  [3, 6]
3   [4, 2]  [1, 4]  [4, 6]
```

I want the new dataframe to look like:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   1   4
2   1   2   3
3   4   1   4
```

The code below generates a data set similar to mine and attempts to do what I want to do in my code without success (d), and mimics what I have seen in a similar question with success(c ; however, only one column). The link to the similar, but different question is here :[Python Pandas: selecting element in array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069235/python-pandas-selecting-element-in-array-column)

```
import pandas as pd

zz = pd.DataFrame([[[1,2],[2,3],[3,6]],[[4,2],[1,4],[4,6]],
               [[1,2],[2,3],[3,6]],[[4,2],[1,4],[4,6]]])
print(zz)

x= zz.dtypes
print(x)

a = pd.DataFrame((zz.columns.values))
b = pd.DataFrame.transpose(a) 
c =zz[0].str[0] # this will give the 1st value for each cell in columns 0
d= zz[[b[0]].values].str[0] #attempt to get 1st value for each cell in all columns
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `apply` and for selecting first value of list use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
print (zz.apply(lambda x: x.str[0]))
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  4
2  1  2  3
3  4  1  4
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (zz.stack().str[0].unstack())
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  4
2  1  2  3
3  4  1  4
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm going to try both your methods and see what runs fastest.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `applymap` which applies the same function to each individual cell in your DataFrame

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  4
2  1  2  3
3  4  1  4
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of `stack` + `unstack`
However, @jezrael already put that answer down... so + 1 from me.

That said, here is a quicker way. By slicing a numpy array

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(zz.values.tolist())[:, :, 0],
    zz.index, zz.columns
)

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  1  4
2  1  2  3
3  4  1  4
```

---

***timing***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the timing info and new method..+1