# Extracting an element of a list in a pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame that contains a list on each column as shown in the example below with only two columns.

```
    Gamma   Beta
0   [1.4652917656926299, 0.9326935235505321, float] [91, 48.611034768515864, int]
1   [2.6008354611105995, 0.7608529935313189, float] [59, 42.38646954167245, int]
2   [2.6386970166722348, 0.9785848171888037, float] [89, 37.9011122659478, int]
3   [3.49336632573625, 1.0411524946972244, float]   [115, 36.211134224288344, int]
4   [2.193991200007534, 0.7955134305428825, float]  [128, 50.03563864975485, int]
5   [3.4574527664490997, 0.9399880977511021, float] [120, 41.841146628802875, int]
6   [3.1190582380554863, 1.0839109431114795, float] [148, 55.990072419824514, int]
7   [2.7757359940789916, 0.8889801332053203, float] [142, 51.08885697101243, int]
8   [3.23820908493237, 1.0587479742892683, float]   [183, 43.831293356668425, int]
9   [2.2509032790941985, 0.8896196407231622, float] [66, 35.9377662201882, int]
```

I'd like to extract for every column the first position of the list on each row to get a DataFrame looking as follows.

```
    Gamma   Beta
0   1.4652917656926299  91
1   2.6008354611105995  59
2   2.6386970166722348  89
...
```

Up to now, my solution would be like `[row[1][0] for row in df_params.itertuples()]`, which I could iterate for every column index of the row and then compose my new DataFrame.

An alternative is `new_df = df_params['Gamma'].apply(lambda x: x[0])` and then to iterate to go through all the columns.

My question is, is there a less cumbersome way to perform this operation?

Comment: Similar question (with one additional way of solving it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069235/python-pandas-selecting-element-in-array-column

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the `str` accessor for lists, e.g.:

```
df_params['Gamma'].str[0]
```

This should work for all columns:

```
df_params.apply(lambda col: col.str[0])
```

Comment: str[0] is nice shot ;)

Comment: Oh wow that's pretty nice. Goodbye list comprehension. Definitely getting my vote.

Comment: :D, :D, :D it is nice

Comment: I wasn't that far off :). Thanks, worked like a charm!

Comment: `str` is an accessor to treat the value as a string, right? What makes this work?

Comment: @Scro, `Series.str[0]` calls [`StringMethods.__getitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4e8306690e8c29080c1886442ffd209c259bcd3d/pandas/core/strings/accessor.py#L240), which ultimately calls [`_str_get`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4e8306690e8c29080c1886442ffd209c259bcd3d/pandas/core/strings/object_array.py#L267) when the key is not a slice. `_str_get` is also how `Series.str.get()` works, and the docs for that function say it can "extract element from lists, tuples, dict, or strings". Thus, some (but not all) methods of the `.str` accessor can work on non-strings.

Answer (score 3):

Itertuples would be pretty slow. You could speed this up with the following:

```
for column_name in df_params.columns:
    df_params[column_name] = [i[0] for i in df_params[column_name]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible for [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html)

```py
df_params['Gamma'].str.get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The given answer fails if your inputs length vary.

Then, you can unnest column-wise and drop the unnecessary ones.

Here is how to unnest. Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-rows) answer.

```
def unnesting(df, explode, axis):
    if axis==1:
        df1 = pd.concat([df[x].explode() for x in explode], axis=1)
        return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
    else :
        df1 = pd.concat([
                         pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix(x) for x in explode], axis=1)
        return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```